# p values in correlation plot (corrplot)

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I want to plot correlations between two matrices, adding the p-values (having white cell where the p-value is higher than 0.05)
I found this code on the `corrplot` package manual.

```
library(corrplot)

cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95) {
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
n <- ncol(mat)
p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
diag(p.mat) <- 0
diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
        tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], conf.level = conf.level)
        p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
        lowCI.mat[i, j] <- lowCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
        uppCI.mat[i, j] <- uppCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
    }
}
return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}

res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, 0.95)

##specialized the insignificant value according to the significant level
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], sig.level = 0.2)
```

I'm supposing that `mtcars` is my data frame...How can I modify the code using two matrices?

I calculated the correlations using `corr.test` in `psych` library.

```
cor.matrix <- corr.test(data1,data2,method="spearman")
```

But if I try:

```
res1 <- cor.mtest(cor.matrix, 0.95)
```

It give me an error...

How can I modify this code?

Comment: what is the matrix M?

Comment: [Here is an introduction to the package](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2107_4eb1adc1e4d44b93b6fde7eb801519fe.html)